# textinput and print all the occurence of those string values in R programming

Tags: r, shiny

I am a beginner in R programming and trying to create a web application.
I created a text input (UI) as:

```
sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(textInput('text1', 'County', value = "", width = '250px', placeholder = NULL), submitButton("Update View")), mainPanel(textOutput('cd')))
```

I would like to display the values of a table that matches the string entered in textinput. Example: if, I enter `alameda` in `textinput` and click on submit option, then all the values matching `alameda` will print in main panel.
The server code is as:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
originaldata <- read.csv(file="Patient_Discharge.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

output$content = renderDataTable({originaldata})

dev <- reactive({
 for (var in originaldata$County_Name) {
   if(input$text1 == var) print(var) else print("left") 
 }
})

output$cd <- renderText({paste(dev)})
})
```

I am getting an error as follow:

> "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

Comment: Direct cause of the error is the last line, where you should use `paste(dev())`. Use a reactive value like a function `dev()`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are trying to apply the function 'paste' on dev, which is a reactive variable. You should treat reactive variables as a function if you want its value. That is: paste(dev()) would solve your error. However, you also have to ensure that the reactive expression for dev has something to return. At the moment, the for-loop will be what is returned by the reactive variable. If I would convert your code:

```
result = c()
for (var in originaldata$County_Name) {
    result <- c(result, ifelse(input$text1 == var, var, "left"))
}
return(result)
```